# Porque los botones Paginate_button del table en el modal no funcionan

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, djangorestframework

```html
  <div class="row mt">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
      <h3><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Tratamiento</h3>
      <div class="showback">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btn-registrar-tratamiento">Registrar Tratamiento</button>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="box">
          <!--
            <div class="box-header">
              <h3 class="box-title">Data Table With Full Features</h3>
            </div>-->
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <div class="box-body">
              <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="table-tratamientos">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>#</th>
                  <th>Paciente</th>
                  <th>Fecha</th>
                  <th>Diente</th>
                  <th>Servicio</th>
                  <th></th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ocultar" id="html-table-pacientes">
    <table class="table " id="table-pacientes">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Apellido</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

```js
// Cargar tabla pacientes
 function cargarTablaPaciente() {
   axios.get("/control/lista_paciente/")
   .then(response => {
     console.log(response.data);

     $("#table-pacientes").DataTable({
       destroy: true,
       pageLength: false,
       data: response.data,
       ordering: false,
       lengthMenu: [ [3, 10, 25, -1], [3, 10, 25, "All"] ],
       //lengthChange: true,
       paging: true,
       columns: [
         { 'data': 'id' },
         { 'data': 'nombres' },
         { 'data': 'apellidos' },
       ]
     });
```

[image: Aqui es el datatable del paciente, aqui todo bien, puedo registrar y usas sus funciones correctamente como el search, show, pages]
[image: agui una hice una prueba con la consulta buscando con el nombre prueba y si lo hace correctamente]
[image: el problema es aqui, que si me hace el llamado de la tabla y todo pero no se puede ocupar la busqueda, ni cuantas filas quiero ver o los botones de las pagina,1,2,3,next]

El problema es que en el modal no me funciona correctamente el DataTables

Aqui es el datatable del paciente, aqui todo bien, puedo registrar y usas sus funciones correctamente como el search, show, pages

agui una hice una prueba con la consulta buscando con el nombre prueba y si lo hace correctamente

el problema es aqui, que si me hace el llamado de la tabla y todo pero no se puede ocupar la busqueda, ni cuantas filas quiero ver o los botones de las pagina,1,2,3,next

y yo quiero usar esas funciones de la datatable,y solo me muestra las filas que yo deseo ver pero hasta ahi con el lengthMenu: [ [3, 10, 25, -1], [3, 10, 25, "All"] ], ese 3 es el show donde solo veo

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden